# Why aren't these ways of creating singletons same as Initialization on Demand Holder (IODH) idiom?

Tags: java, singleton

Hi I am trying to understand the JMM and why certain operations work the way they do.

I want to understand why the following ways of using a static variable and a static initializer is **not the same as** [Initialization on Demand Holder (IODH) idiom](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#dcl).

**Option 1: Just initialize a static variable**

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

private Singleton() {}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Static Initializer**

```
public class Singleton {
private static Singleton instance = null;

static {
    instance = new Singleton();
    }

private Singleton() {
   }

public static Singleton getInstance() { return instance;}   
}
```

**Why I think that these should be same as IODH idiom :**

- [JLS](https://web.archive.org/web/20141231132932/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html) specifies static initializers are not touched until someone touches the actual class. **So, this applies to static variables right ?**

> explicit initializers for static fields are executed as part of
> initialization

- All classes are loaded on-demand by the classloader.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: These two ways are semantically identical. A static variable with an initializer is syntactic sugar for an uninitialized variable + static initializer block. (Actually, not quite, you initialize with null, then immediately overwrite with a value - initializing with null serves no purpose, though).

Comment: You are correct that this won't be initialized until you touch the class. The initialize-on-demand idiom would give you the ability to access other static fields/methods on the `Singleton` class, without creating the instance.

Comment: @AndyTurner So if I wanted just a singleton the static initializer method is thread safe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They (option 1 and 2) are not the same as IODH. The purpose of IODH is to specify that static field will be initialized when `getInstance()` method is called, and not the class is touched by any way. So it makes static reference initialization more explicit. As for reference, this is how IODH looks like:

```
public class Singleton {
  private Singleton() {}

  private static class Holder {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
  }

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, the reason why the object is initialized when `getInstance()` is called is because all classes in the JVM are loaded on demand. And this case the inner class is only loaded when `getInstance()` is called right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the idea behind IODH is that the Holder class is miminal, so no other use will cause it to load besides the getInstance call.

Answer (score 0):

In case of eager initialization, whenever a class is referenced in a code at runtime, the class definition (from the .class file) is loaded and all of its static members (incl. static blocks) are initialized.
For instance, if you have a method like this in your singleton class and you reference it in a client code, (`Singleton.doSomething`), you will see the class gets instantiated despite you are not explicitly calling `getInstance()` method because the static member is getting initialized.

```
public class Singleton {
  private Singleton() {
      System.out.println("Singleton initialized");
  }

  private static Singleton instance = new Singleton();

  private Singleton() {}

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return instance;
    }

  public static void doSomething() {
      System.out.println("Singleton doing something");
    }
}
```

However, when you do the same thing for IODH singleton, only the `"LazyRegistryIODH doSomething"` message will be printed out to console and the constructor of `LazyRegistryIODH`  is not getting called since there is no static fields or blocks to be initialized.

```
public class LazyRegistryIODH {
    private LazyRegistryIODH() {
        System.out.println("LazyRegistryIODH initialized");
    }

    private static class Holder {
        static final LazyRegistryIODH INSTANCE = new LazyRegistryIODH();
    }

    protected static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("LazyRegistryIODH doSomething");
    }

    public static LazyRegistryIODH getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```